# Genus of a plane curve of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_iX+b_iY+Z) = Z^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anybody know the genus of the following (projective) plane curve?: 
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (a_iX+b_iY+Z) = Z^n$$
where the $a_i$'s and the $b_i$'s are complex numbers with $a_j \ne a_i\ne b_i \ne b_j$ for every $i\ne j$.

Comment: Everybody does. If  $a_i$, $b_j$ are general enough, the curve is a smooth plane curve of degree $n$, hence of genus $\frac{1}{2} (n-1)(n-2)$.

Comment: What the heck, abx? MO is a site for mathematicians, not algebraic geometers. There is plenty of room in math for people not to know this, plus as Peter Mueller's answer shows, there is something to be careful about even here.

Comment: In the particular example of interest to me $n=\frac{p-1}{2}$, $a_i=\zeta_p^{2i}+\zeta_p^{-2i}-2$ and $b_i=\zeta_p^{i}+\zeta_p^{-i}-2$, with $p$ odd prime and $\zeta_p$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity. So the original curve has integral coefficients but the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are not integers. For $p=3$ and $p=5$ the genus is $0$, for $p=7$ the curve is smooth, so that, the genus is 1. For $p=11$ and $p=13$, there is a unique singular point and its multiplicity is 2, so that genus are 5 and 9 respectively.

Comment: Even though the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are not integers, they are nonetheless algebraic integers.  You can reduce your curve modulo a prime divisor $q$ of $n$.  Then, if you check that the reductions $(\overline{a}_i,\overline{b}_i)$ are all nonzero and linearly independent, then the reduction curve is smooth so that abx's comment applies.

Comment: @Jason Starr: In which sense can, for $n\ge3$, the $n$ pairs $(\bar a_i,\bar b_i)\in\overline{\mathbb F_q}^2$ be linearly independent?

Comment: Sorry: "pairwise linearly independent".

Comment: If the projective lines given by $Z+\overline{a}_iX+\overline{b}_iY = 0$ are distinct, and if all pairwise intersections do not lie on the line $Z=0$, then it is straightforward to see that the curve is smooth.

Comment: Dear Jason, actually the conditions implies that the intersections of two of these lines is contained in the line $Z=0$. This follows by straightforward calculations. In any case I know that for $p=11$, $(1,-1,1)$ is a singular point, so there is no hope for the curve to be smooth. The question is how to control the singular points and its multiplicities.

Comment: @AngeldelRio: If you can estimate from above the number of such intersection points on lines, then you can bound from below the geometric genus, assuming this curve is irreducible.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I know that the curve is irreducible. I am not an algebraic geometer, so I don't know the reason why bounding the number of intersection points will give a bound on the genus. I guess the intersection points are related with the singularities but I don't see how or why). Of course, the number of intersections is at most $\binom{n}{2}$. I guess you are considering that maybe some intersection collapse. Actually if $a_ib_j\ne a_jb_i$, the intersection is $(0,0,0)$, i.e. there is no really intersection. This holds for every $i\ne j$ in my curve ($p=11$) but the curve is not smooth.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Do the intersections of two lines $Z+a_iX+b_iY=0$ have something to do with the singular points? This would be odd because I know that there are not singularities in the line $Z=0$.

Comment: You said before that you know that there are singularities on the line $Z=0$, and now you are saying that there are not lines?  Please read about the connection between the geometric genus and the singular points, for instance, in Example 3.9.2, p. 393 of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry"

Comment: Did I say that there are singularities in $Z=0$? I think I didn't say that. I said that the intersection of two different lines $Z+a_iX+b_iY=0$ is contained in $Z=0$. This will give a singularity if $a_ib_j=a_jb_i$ but in the cases I am interested this does not occur for every $i\ne j$. So there are not singularities in $Z=0$. Hence the question is about the singularities the affine plane.

Answer (score 2):

Even under the conditions on the $a_i$ and $b_i$, the genus cannot be expressed in terms of $n$. For instance for $n=3$, the genus is generically $1$. However, if for instance $a_1b_2=a_2b_1$, then the cubic curve is singular, so has genus $0$.

Comment: It depends on whether genus means arithmetic or geometric genus. Of course, you and probably the OP mean the latter.

Comment: I mean geometric genus.

Comment: For me it will be enough to have a lower bound for the genus for $n\ge 5$. More precisely, is it true that if $n\ge 5$ then the genus is at least 2?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give it a try from a different point of view. I'll work over the complex numbers. I did not really work out the details carefully, but in any case I hope that the idea is useful.

The linear forms $a_jX+b_jY+Z$ are linearly independent when taken by three. Proof: write the relevant 3x3 matrix for three different indices. After some column operations you get the Vandermonde matrix of the real parts of $\zeta^i,\zeta^j,\zeta^k$, which are different.

Suppose that the curve in question has an irreducible component of genus $g$ (I did not check irreducibility, but I don't need it; this is why I use a component). The normalization of it gives a map $F:C\to \mathbb{P}^2$ where $C$ is smooth projective of genus $g$. Taking the coordinates $X,Y,Z$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ we write $F=[f:g:h]$ with $f,g,h$ in the function field of $C$, and we let $d$ be the height of $[f:g:h]$. Consider the lines $L=\{Z=0\}$ (this is my line at infinity, to fix ideas) and $H_j=\{a_jX+b_jY+Z=0\}$; by the previous paragraph the $H_i$ are in general position. Let $S=F^{-1}(L)$, this is a subset of $C$ and we have $\# S\le d$.

The fact that $F$ has image contained in the zero set of the curve in question gives that $F|_{C\smallsetminus S}$ never hits the lines $H_j$. At this point we invoke some result from Nevanlinna theory. Corollary 4 in J. T.-Y. Wang's paper "The truncated second main theorem of function fields" (JNT 1996) will do it: we get
$$
(n-4)d\le 0 + 3\max\{0,2g-2+\#S\}\le 3\max\{0,2g-2+d\}.
$$
For $n\ge 5$ we are forced to have $2g-2+d>0$ so that
$$
(n-4)d\le 6g-6+3d.
$$
You are interested in avoiding genus $0$ and $1$, so we can assume $g\le 1$ obtaining
$$
(n-4)d\le 3d.
$$
This is not possible for $n>7$, so, such curves don't have components of genus $0$ or $1$. This proves the result for $p> 15$ ($p$ does not need to be prime as far as I can see, taking $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit.** There is a serious **gap** in the argument below.  The issue, the same one that arose in two similar questions, is that the Euler identity does not hold in positive characteristic $q$.  Therefore, for $q$ a prime dividing $n$, the critical locus of the degree $n$, dehomogenized polynomial $$f(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i x + b_iy)$$ on $\mathbb{A}^2$ is not necessarily $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$.  I have computed examples of such polynomials where the critical locus is precisely $\{0\}$ (for instance, $(p,q) = (5,2)$ or $(7,3)$), but I am not certain  for which primes $p>3$ and for which prime divisors $q$ of $n=(p-1)/2$ the critical locus equals $\{0\}$.  I am leaving the following argument for the moment, and I will try to sort out the critical locus of $f$.

In the OP's specific case, $p$ is an odd prime, $p=2n+1$, $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$, and $a_i=\zeta_p^{2i}-2+\zeta_p^{-2i}$, $b_i=\zeta_p^{i} - 2 + \zeta_p^{-i}$.  Of course the set of primitive roots of $1$ has size $p-1=2n$.  There is an action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ on this set sending a root $\zeta$ to $\zeta^{-1}$.  This action is fixed point free, since otherwise $2$ divides $p$.

Although the OP does not quite say this, I assume that the index $i$ ranges over the $n$ orbits for this action.  In particular, since every such primitive root $\zeta$ is the square of another primitive root (squaring is an automorphism of a cyclic group of odd order), I am going to reindex with $i=2j$.  Thus, in my indexing, $$\alpha_j = \zeta_p^{4j}-2 + \zeta_p^{-4j} = (\zeta_p^{2j}-\zeta_p^{-2j})^2, \ \beta_j = \zeta_p^{2j}-2+\zeta_p^{-2j} = (\zeta_p^{j}-\zeta_p^{-j})^2.$$

Now let $q$ be a prime that divides $n$, say $n=qm$, $p=2qm+1$.  In other words, $p\equiv 1 \ (\text{mod}\ 2q)$.  Let $R$ be the Dedekind domain $\mathbb{Z}[1/p][\zeta_p]/\langle \zeta_p^p-1 \rangle$.  It is straightforward to compute that $R$ is finite and étale over $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$.  The elements $\alpha_p$ and $\beta_p$ are as defined above.  The curve $C_R\subset \mathbb{P}^2_R$ is the $R$-flat Cartier divisor with defining polynomial
$$
f(X,Y,Z) = \left( \prod_j (Z+\alpha_j X + \beta_j Y) \right) - Z^n.
$$
To prove that the generic fiber of $C_R$ over $\text{Frac}(R)$ is smooth, it suffices to prove smoothness after reducing modulo $q$.

Since $q$ is relatively prime to $q$, there exists a least positive integer $r$ such that $q^r\equiv 1\ (\text{mod} \ p)$.  Let $k$ be the finite field with $q^r$ elements.  Then the multiplicative group $k^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $q^r-1$.  Since $p$ divides $q^r-1$, there exists an element $\zeta$ in $k^\times$ that has order $q$.  This gives a ring homomorphism $R\to k$ sending $\zeta_P$ to $\zeta$.    Thus also 
In particular, we can form the images in $k$ of the elements $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$. 
As above, since $\zeta$ has order $p$, and since $2$ does not divide $p$, no $\zeta^j-\zeta^{-j}$ equals $0$.  Thus $\beta_j = (\zeta^j-\zeta^{-j})^2$ is not zero.  Similarly, if some $\zeta^j = -\zeta^{-j}$, then $\zeta^j$ has order $4$ in $k^\times$ rather than order $p$.  Thus also $\alpha_j = \beta_j(\zeta^j+\zeta^{-j})^2$ is nonzero.

I claim that for distinct indices $j\neq \ell$, also $\alpha_\ell \beta_j - \alpha_j\beta_\ell$ is nonzero in $k$. Since $j\neq \ell$, both $\zeta^{\ell} \neq \zeta^j$ and $\zeta^{\ell} \neq \zeta^{-j}$.  Using again that squaring is an automorphism of the cyclic group $\langle \zeta \rangle \subset k^\times$ of order $p$, we also have
$$
\zeta^{2\ell} \neq \zeta^{2j}, \ \ \zeta^{2\ell} \neq \zeta^{-2j}.
$$
By direct computation, $$
\alpha_\ell\beta_j - \alpha_j\beta_\ell = \beta_\ell\beta_j((\zeta^{2\ell}-\zeta^{2j}) - (\zeta^{-2j}-\zeta^{-2\ell})).$$
As above, $\beta_\ell$ and $\beta_j$ are nonzero.  Therefore, by way of contradiction, assume that
$$
\zeta^{2\ell} - \zeta^{2j} = \zeta^{-2j}-\zeta^{-2\ell}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $\zeta^{2\ell+2j}$ gives,
$$
\zeta^{2\ell}\zeta^{2j}(\zeta^{2\ell}-\zeta^{2j}) = (\zeta^{2\ell} - \zeta^{2j}).
$$
Therefore, either we have
$$
\zeta^{2\ell} = \zeta^{2j},
$$
or we have
$$
\zeta^{2\ell} = \zeta^{-2j}.
$$
But both of these contradict the hypothesis that $\ell \neq j$.  Therefore, by way of contradiction, $\alpha_\ell \beta_j - \alpha_j \beta_\ell$ is nonzero.  In particular, the three lines $Z=0$, $Z+\alpha_jX + \beta_jY =0$, and $Z+\alpha_\ell X + \beta_\ell Y$ are not collinear in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$. Since this holds for every $j$ and $\ell$, the curve $C_k$ is smooth.

Therefore, combined with the comments above, the reduction curve $C_k$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$ is smooth.  So the curve $C_{\text{Frac}(R)}$ is also smooth over $\text{Frac}(R)$.  Therefore the base change to $\mathbb{C}$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ of degree $n$ and genus $(n-1)(n-2)/2$, just as abx explained.